# Variation of scalar field - this equality is true?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation

I was using a computer program to do tensor computations, and found a mismatch between my result and the computer's result. The results would match if
$$g^{cd} \nabla_c \phi \nabla_d \phi = g_{cd} \nabla^c \phi \nabla^d \phi$$
for a scalar field. Is this true?

Comment: I think that something is wrong with the right hand side indices, it is not scalar for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because indices are [raised and lowered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism) by the metric tensor. In particular $\nabla^a ~:=~ g^{ab} \nabla_b$.